# Call a JavaScript function into another JavaScript function in a Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, javascript, visualforce-component

I have a main page, with a main controller, that contains some JavaScript code:

```
<apex:page controller = "controller1">
  <script>
    function function1(){
     //I want to call the function 2 here
    }
  </script>
</apex:page1>
```

And a component with some JavaScript code too:

```
<apex:component controller="controller2">
 <script>
   function2(){ //Some code here }
 </script>
</apex:component>
```

Well, I want to call the function 2, contained in the component, into my main page, like in the code above...

Is it possible? If yes, how?

The function2 in my component's JavaScript code refers to a method in my controller2, but I don't know if this information is useful for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can access directly.

```
<apex:page controller="OppsController">
    <apex:form >
        <c:Test></c:Test>
        <input type="button" value="test" onclick="test();"/>
        <script>
        function test(){ 
        function2();
        }
        </script>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Component

```
<apex:component >
    <script>
   function function2(){
   alert('in component');
   }
 </script>
</apex:component>
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer @Ratan ! It seems to be working with my code :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure if this would work and assuming you want `function1()` to be called as soon as the page loads to call `function2()`, here are some ideas:

First things first would be to check whether or not the JavaScript code is rendered into the page. Make sure that when you view the page source, `function2()` exists in there.

The next thing I would do is to only call `function1()` when the DOM has loaded. If you're using jQuery, that might look a little like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function1();
})

function1() {
  function2();
}
```

If you're using pure JavaScript, that'd be something like below:

```
window.onload = function() {
  function1();
}

function1() {
  function2();
}
```

If it is that you're calling `function1()` only to call `function2()`, and it has no other logic or requirement, you wouldn't really need `function1()` at all, and you could just call `function2()` within the `onload` or `$(document).ready()` functions themselves.

Comment: I need the function1 to call 3 functions from 3 components, and then I call the  function1 into a button, like in the Ratan's answer (my fault, I forgot to say that into my question...) but I keep your answer in mind for other javascrip problems, thank you :)

Comment: @dou No problem, glad it's somewhat useful! :)